# Checking long-term memory usage of iOS apps

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

Instruments can be used to check the short-term memory usage of an app, but is there any way to check the memory consumption of your iOS app when it's been used heavily and foregrounded/backgrounded on iOS 4, say for a week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep instruments open for awhile, through multiple uses of your application.  Try every possible iteration of what a user could do.  Let it sit, throw it in the background.. etc.

If you do not have any memory problems in the short to mid term, it stands good reason that you will not have any in the long term.

E

Comment: Thanks - that's good advice.  Since posting this question I've learned about the problem of abandoned memory (as opposed to leaked memory) and using object allocation markers in Instruments to check that repeating operations do not consume more and more memory over time.  This in detailed in the WWDC 2010 session entitled "Advanced Memory Analysis with Instruments" which can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

Comment: Thanks for the tidbit found in the vid.  I will definitely check it out.